# JS Library react-d3-tree too limited for visualizing and animating a B-Tree as a React Component?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, web-frontend

I am a complete begginer to react, javascript, and web development in general.
I want to build a web-application in React, that can visualize a B-Tree. I also want to be able to modify the B-Tree and provide animations for how the Tree-structure would rotate and balance itself.

I looked at the documentation of react-d3-tree, but it seemed very limited and I am not sure if I can customize it enough to meet the requirements listed above.

Do you think I could implement something like that with react-d3-tree, do you have experience with that library or is it too limited? Do you have any other suggestions of what I could use, or how you would implement that yourself?

I appreciate any advice or suggestions thank you.

Comment: I was able to make it work, if anyone is interested or looking to do something similar, you can take a look at the git I created: https://github.com/mattik01/Tree-Visualizer